# Choosing the right PartitionKey for a date-based worldwide DocumentDB app

Tags: database, azure, geospatial, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I'm developing a **worldwide** application in which most searches are based on **geospacial data** (nearest records given coordinates) and **date ranges**.

So, basically is likely the main searches of applications like AirBnb, Booking, etc.

Which **Partition Key** should I choose in a DocumentDB Partitioned Collection considering these context?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**: like I told to Matias (see answers), me and my friend we're thinking about something like the Country.
The app is all about searches. And another important thing is that we have dates. Tons of dates.
Since we are new to DDB, our question is: "**what happens if we choose Country as Partition Key and our queries must search within different countries?**". i.e. a georadius search near country borders.

Comment: Could you provide some additional context, e.g. what is your schema, are your queries typically for a booking, property, or user (for example), ready-heavy vs. write-heavy, etc.   A good read on partitioning is [Partitioning and scaling in Azure DocumentDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-partition-data).

Comment: Hi Denny, I have updated the question, thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like Matias mentioned, some more information will help us provide a better recommendation. I've added some ideas/options for partition key selection below:

- Use a generic partition key like user ID or product ID. In this model, your geospatial queries will be executed across partitions, but since DocumentDB locally builds a spatial index within partitions, this might meet your performance needs
- Use a partitioning scheme based on the [GeoHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) of the location. This will ensure that data points in similar locations will get placed on the same partitions. This will require some additional work in your app to add "GeoHash > abcdef and GeoHash < abcfff" clauses to narrow down query execution to a few partitions
- Partition based on a property like **country**, if most of your queries fall within a single country. Rare queries that need to span countries will also perform well (though not as low latency as queries against a single partition/country), as they can use the local index within each partition. You might need to handle special cases separately. For example if US has >30-40% of your data, you might want to choose a hybrid approach where US data uses state as the partition key, and countries with lesser data use the country as the partition key. A composite key of country + day/month/year might also work depending on the data distribution.
- If your queries are spread evenly across time ranges, you can consider using dates as the partition key. But for most applications, since recent data is more frequently accessed, this is not a good option.

Comment: Hi Aravind, thank you for your answer.
The point is that the app is all about Geoposition and Dates. We are thinking about Country or something like Time Ranges, but we haven't distinct Time Ranges, 'cause queries could ask for "any" date span.
I have updated the question and I have commented the Matias' answer too.

Comment: thanks - edited my answer inline with a country based approach.

Comment: @AravindKrishnaR. Is it possible to provide a sample code of above answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing a bit more is hard to say but I'd start with these official Partition guide: [Partitioning and scaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-partition-data), especially the section about [Designing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-partition-data#designing-for-partitioning).

Main points should be throughput distribution (You don't want "hot spots") and Transaction atomicity probably. Remember that when you issue a Query it can spans multiple Partitions and DDB will distribute throughput evenly (you can use this feature with the [EnableCrossPartitionQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions.enablecrosspartitionquery.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) option).

So, what truly determines which would be the best partition keys really depend on how your data is distributed and how your queries are built.

Since the app is worldwide, maybe the best Partition approach is to divide by country/continent/region (one of those) but it really depends on the amount of data, it should be evenly distributed to avoid having a really hot partition/zone.

Finally, you can also check the [Performance and scale test example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-performance-testing) and [DocumentDB performance tips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-performance-tips) to work on improving performance.

Comment: Thank you Matias. I know that I haven't provided a lot of informations, but this is because I'm thinking about the architectural design of the application.
Me and my friend were thinking about a spacial approach, expecially we're thinking about something like the Country. 
But we are new to DDB and our question is: "what happens when the query must search within different countries?". i.e. a georadius search near country borders.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using partitioning because you have a lot of data but expect queries to return one or a few records only based on the geospatial criteria alone then something like country may work as it will cut out a lot of irrelevant data immediately and indexes within the partition will allow the required documents to be found quickly.   This will likely cause irregular partition sizes though - imagine if Russia and China end up in the same partition.

If, however, your queries will return a lot of documents based on the geospatial criteria and you wish to either extract all of those records or apply further filtering or other functions over them then you will want to spread that processing over as many partitions as possible. In this case you want a partition key that will spread data evenly over the partitions.   If you expect queries to combine multiple document types for the same coordinates, user id or site id etc then it is best to have a key based on that value so that all related documents can be processed together within the same partition.

In practical applications I have found using an incrementing value as partition key to be the best general purpose solution as it allows queries to be processed evenly over all partitions.